# How can I schedule my computer to shutdown at a certain time?

Tags: python-3.x

I run a program which has a lot of computation that takes a lot of time for outputs. I thought that it might be a good idea if I could turn off the PC after the output has been received. so I used the code below (which works fine by the way):

```
def shutdown():
  import os
  os.system("shutdown /s /t 90")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
  shutdown()
```

But now I have another program (IDM) running simultaneously which works from 2 AM until 7 AM.
My question is that how can I design a simple program that shut down the PC only if the PC time has passed over 7 AM. 
Can anyone help me with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the current time, and loop until it passes the specified hour before shutting down, e.g.:

```
import os
import time

def shutdown(threshold=7):
    while time.gmtime().tm_hour < threshold:
        time.sleep(300)  # wait 5 minutes
    os.system("shutdown /s /t 90")
```

and call it as you call it now.

The threshold sets the hour after which to proceed with the shutdown, by default its set to 7. Keep in mind, tho, that it uses your system clock (most probably UTC) so you have to account for the difference when specifying your threshold.

Of course, if you don't want to shutdown the system at all, even when the time passes, if the script was called before the threshold, you can use:

```
def shutdown(threshold=7):
    if time.gmtime().tm_hour >= threshold:
        os.system("shutdown /s /t 90")
```

instead.